# Use JQuery Cycle with custom Javascript

Tags: 7, javascript

I have build a view with a HTML-list were all my images are listed. Goal is to create a JQuery Cycle with those images, but for some reason, my custom Javascript isn't working...

Here is the HTML generated by Drupal:

```
<div class="homepage-slider">
  <ul>
    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd -views-row-first>
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-front-slider-image">
        <div class="field-content">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even>
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-front-slider-image">
        <div class="field-content">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd -views-row-last>
      <div class="views-field views-field-field-front-slider-image">
        <div class="field-content">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my custom Javascript I wrote:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.initFrontPageSlider = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $('body').once('initFrontPageSlider', function() {
                $('.homepage-slider').cycle({
                    fx: 'fade' 
                });
            });
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

But for some reason, my image-list isn't picking up my javascript. What's missing on this?

Comment: why dont you use the views slideshow module instead.

Comment: That doesn't fit my needs. I need my Cycle to be customized in a way the module doesn't provide...

Comment: have you tried putting it in the window load function?

Comment: $(window).bind('load', function() { instead of $('body').once('initFrontPageSlider', function() {

Comment: Thanks for the try, but that didn't work out...

Comment: where did you place the js?

Comment: Where it belongs... `sites/all/themes/js`

Comment: and have you added that using the add js function or in the .info file?

Comment: Yep, the JS-file is recognized by the Drupal website, that's not the problem...

Comment: the .cycle function does not seems to take the <ul> it works with just just the img tag

Comment: Meaning? I should call my img-tag instead of the `<ul>`-tag?

Comment: you need to call the ul and with in ul you should place data-cycle-slides="li" so the ul would be <ul data-cycle-slides="li"> and the cycle code should be $('.homepage-slider ul')

Comment: I think you're confusing some arguments... I've never seen an `ul` with a `data-cycle-slides`-argument. Are you sure about this?

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/

Comment: I have tested the same in my local system as well

Comment: @MohammedShameem You're linking to the wrong script, Cycle2 and Cycle are different things. OP is almost 100% definitely using plain 'ol Cycle

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb, but aren't you suppose to call .cycle() on the <ul> element instead of the parent div? If you call it on div.homepage-slider then cycle will try to cycle the children (<ul>) and because there's only 1 child element it doesn't progress further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cycle the `<li>`'s then you need to call `.cycle()` on the `<ul>` element. At the moment looks like you're trying to cycle the `<ul>` elements inside the `<div class="homepage-slider">`. If there's only 1 child element cycle doesn't progress further since there's nothing to cycle.

Comment: `$('.homepage-slider ul')` worked perfect!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The jquery cycle needs to define the tag that the child is going to use this is set by defining `data-cycle-slides="tag"`.

So in your example it should be `data-cycle-slides="li"`
This should be placed in the tag that wraps the `li` in this case it is `ul` so the `ul` should be `<ul data-cycle-slides="li">` or you could place the slideshow class also within  this like `<ul class="homepage-slider" data-cycle-slides="li">`

In the first case the it would be `$('.homepage-slider ul').cycle({`
and in the second case it should be `$('.homepage-slider').cycle({`

EDIT : This one is for cycle2 and might not be correct in the said question. I guess the as Clive mentioned $('.homepage-slider ul').cycle({` should be enough.

[For reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/)

Comment: For the record, I didn't vote this one down. Do you have a JSFiddle to make your point?

Comment: jQuery Cycle has never needed an explicit definition of `data-cycle-slides` to work, `$('.homepage-slider ul').cycle({` is sufficient. The reference you linked to is for Cycle2 (different script) which I'm sure the OP would have mentioned had he been using it

Comment: sorry for that @Clive I guess I overlooked that point

Comment: yes @Clive is right you just need the $('.homepage-slider ul').cycle({ and not the data data-cycle-slides="li"

Comment: I didn't even know there was a cycle2 actually, thanks for pointing it out :)